# Cookie persistence not working in OWIN authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-mvc-5, owin

I'm developing an MVC5 website that uses the OWIN authentication system (`Microsoft.Owin v4.1.0` via NuGet). I validate a user's login credentials against a database, and then use the OWIN `IAuthenticationManager` to sign them in. Here is the relevant code:

```
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;

public class AuthManager : IAuthManager
{
    private readonly IAuthenticationManager AuthenticationManager;

    public AuthManager()
    {
        this.AuthenticationManager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
    }

    public void SignIn(AppUserState appUserState, bool rememberMe)
    {
        AuthenticationProperties authenticationProperties = new AuthenticationProperties()
        {
            AllowRefresh = true,
            IsPersistent = rememberMe,
            ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(14),
            IssuedUtc = DateTime.UtcNow
        };

        List<Claim> claims = new List<Claim>();
        claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, appUserState.EmailAddress));
        claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, appUserState.Name));
        claims.Add(new Claim("userState", appUserState.ToString()));

        ClaimsIdentity identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

        this.AuthenticationManager.SignIn(authenticationProperties, identity);
    }
}
```

The sign-in process works, however persistence does not. After around 30-60 mins the session always ends, despite `IsPersistent` being set to `true`. When I step through in the debugger and examine the `authenticationProperties` object, I can see that `IsPersistent` is indeed true.

I've read online that this is the flag that determines if your application should keep your user logged in even if the user is not actively using the site. However the user's session always ends.

One thing I've recognised is that the `AuthenticationProperties` class has a dictionary object inside it:

[image: AuthenticationProperties]

When I open the dictionary, I can see that there is a key labelled `.persistent` which has a blank value. I have tried setting this value to `True` (to copy the behaviour of the `.refresh` key) - but this simply had no effect.

[image: AuthenticationProperties]

I don't think the above issue is related to the problem but I thought I should share what investigation I had already performed.

**How can I prevent the user from being automatically logged-out?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it was nothing to do with cookie expiry times. I tried setting the `ExpireTimeSpan` to 14 days (as a test) but it made no difference - I was still automatically logged out.

However I was looking at that same method (`ConfigureAuth`) and saw I had the following code:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
    ExpireTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(14, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
    Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
    {
        OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
            validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
            regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
    }
});
```

As a test, I set the `validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),` to 3000 minutes instead. I was no longer being logged out after 30 minutes. So the reason my sessions were ending is because clearly the call to `SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity` is returning that the current user is unauthorized!

Answer (score 1):

Persistent cookies just aren't purged when you close the browser session, they can still expire. Set `ExpireTimeSpan` in your `CookieAuthenticationOptions` to something longer.

Comment: Thanks, this wasn't the cause of the issue but you did point me in the right direction. I'd forgotten about the default authentication steps listed in `Startup.Auth.cs`.